# convert .csv file to .vtp file (vmtk PolyData type data)

Tags: python, csv, vtk

I'm working to convert the data of a line in a csv file (comma separated file) to a .vtp file.

What I have done is to store the points in the .csv file into a vtkPolyData type variable. The vtkPolyData can be displayed with the render window correctly.

Then I tried to use vtkPolyDataWriter to write the vtkPolyData into a vtp file. But It did not work

```
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInput(vtkpoint.getVtkPolyData) 
## vtkpoint is an instance of a class which I wrote to store the csv data,
## and .getVtkPolyData returns the vtkPolyData typed data 
writer.SetFileName('TestCenterline.vtp')
writer.SetFileTypeToBinary()
writer.Write()
```

This vtp file is not readable.

Comment: You should be using vtkXMLPolyDataWriter. vtkPolyData writer is an old class. You can also use Paraview to try to open whatever file you write to see if it valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect the file by reading its content, use

```
writer->SetDataModeToAscii();
```

instead if binary.

Also  `vtkpoint.getVtkPolyData` looks a bit suspect. Maybe it's just bad naming or bad copy/paste,  but are you sure that that is the  actual polydata and not just a method? Are you able to get the correct value by calling  `vtkpoint.getVtkPolyData.GetNumberOfPoints()`?